# spring-integration-mqtt Route message from Input Topic1 to Output Topic2

Tags: java, spring, mqtt, consumer, producer

i'm from 3 days on this problem: 
I'm using spring-integration-mqtt for read from topic1 a simple message like a json:

```
{speed:40,
position:"NewYork"
}
```

if speed > 50 write "ok" on Topic2.

I read correctly json.
but when i write "ok" in Topic2 i have this error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Failed to publish to MQTT in the [bean 'mqttOutbound'; defined in: 'class path resource [it/almaviva/mqtt/Configuration/Producer/Producer.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@2b95e48b']; nested exception is Connessione già in corso (32110)
```

This is class Consumer that read and write on Producer..

```
@Configuration
public class Consumer {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

@Autowired MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory;
@Autowired
Producer producer;
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
//@Autowired
//static Producer.ProducerGateway gw;

@Bean
public MessageChannel topicChannel(){
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public MessageProducer mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
            Parameters.MQTT_CLIENT_ID, mqttClientFactory, Parameters.TOPICS[0]);
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(topicChannel());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "topicChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return message -> {
        OduModel model = JsonUtility.convertToOduModel(String.valueOf(message.getPayload()));
        logger.info(model.toString());
        boolean condition = DataProcessor.processOduModel(model);
        logger.info(String.valueOf(condition));
        //ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Producer.class).context();
        Producer.ProducerGateway gw = context.getBean(Producer.ProducerGateway.class);
        if (condition){
            gw.sendToMqtt("OK"!, Parameters.TOPICS[1]);

        }
        else{
            gw.sendToMqtt("No OK", Parameters.TOPICS[1]);
        }

    };
}
```

}

Parameters.TOPICS[0] is topic1 where i read message incoming.
Parameters.TOPICS[1] is "topic2" where i write "ok" or "non ok".

Is correct use in particular this code in MessageHandler??

```
 Producer.ProducerGateway gw = context.getBean(Producer.ProducerGateway.class);
        if (condition){
            gw.sendToMqtt(""OK", Parameters.TOPICS[1]);

        }
        else{
            gw.sendToMqtt("not OK", Parameters.TOPICS[1]);
        }
```

I use this dependency on pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Thanks very much.
Regards